# python : Collatz Sequence

Tags: python, beginner, collatz-sequence

I am a beginner in python. I found this problem in the book **Automate the Boring Stuff with Python**. How can I improve this program using latest version of python.

```
def generateCollatzSequence(number):
    print(str(number) + " ")

    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number / 2
            print(str(number) + " ")

        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = (3 * number) + 1
            print(str(number) + " ")

#print("Enter number: ")
inputNumber = int(input("Enter number: "))
generateCollatzSequence(inputNumber)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205785/35991, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/194837/35991, and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221741/35991 for quite similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your function is called `generate` but it doesn't return anything. Instead `display` would be a better name.
- It would be better if you had two functions one to generate the values, one to display them.
- Function names should be `lower_snake_case` to be idiomatic.
- `+ " "` is not needed, as print makes the value go to the next line anyway.
- `str(number)` also isn't needed as `print` will do this automatically for you.

Thanks @[Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75307/toby-speight):

- You can move the `print` to be after both the `if` and the `else`.

```
def generate_collatz_sequence(number):
    output = [number]
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number / 2
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = (3 * number) + 1
        output.append(number)

def display_collatz_sequence(values):
    for number in values:
        print(number)
```

If you want this to still display values in real time, then you can make `generate_collatz_sequence` a generator function.

```
def generate_collatz_sequence(number):
    yield number
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number / 2
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = (3 * number) + 1
        yield number
```